# Do clock event on a collection of items in a html page by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, click, fetch

I am working on a web project. In order to get information about each contact in contact list, I have to click on their name, then the webpage by a jquery or javascript approach adds some new DIVs to the page which have the contact information. So, it seems I have to write a JavaScript function make an automatic clicks on each of contact list items and wait few seconds and fetch the added DIVs. Unfortunately, I do not know that how is it possible?

Comment: May you read [ask], and add your efforts using a [mcve] _in the question itself_. **Remember, we're here to help, not do your work for you.**

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good approach what you are asking for, 
I have a suggestion

1) Try to populate the information along with the contact list itself
   (If you are populating the contact list from an api you must need to be provided with the information corresponding to each contact. It would be better than what you are trying)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get Contact details along with contact list and store it in some session or local storage or even in some global variable. Then on clicking the contact list based on Contact name ID filter data from session and display it where ever you want